# Parsing title and link from html page

Tags: php

I wanna get the title and link from this html page :

```
<div class="gs_r">
    <h3 class="gs_rt">
        <span class="gs_ctc">[BOOK]</span>
        <a href="http://example.com" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','1')">titleA</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="gs_ggs gs_fl">
        <a href="http://exampleA.pdf" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'gga','gga','1')">
```

How can I get them?

here's the code :

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://example.com';
$html = file_get_html($url);
//get the first link
foreach($html->find('span[class=gs_ctc]')as $Link){
echo $link;
}
foreach($html->find('div[class=gs_ggs gs_fl]')as $docLink){
echo $docLink;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried an XML parsing solution?

Comment: From what html page? Your question is poorly written, and your code is incomplete. Please consider improving it so you can be helped better. And also, what have you done/tried so far.

Comment: Is that the *whole* HTML page?

Comment: @LeeR yes, from html page. I wanna get the informations : http://example.com, titleA, and http://exampleA.pdf

Comment: @Rocket no, I just took the part of html page that I want to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first link, it's a sibling of the `<span>`.  Try this:

```
//get the first link
foreach($html->find('span[class=gs_ctc]') as $link){
    $link = $link->next_sibling();
    echo $link->plaintext;
    echo $link->href;
}
```

As for the 2nd link, it's a child of the `<div>`:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=gs_ggs gs_fl]') as $docLink){
    $link = $docLink->first_child();
    echo $link->href;
}
```

EDIT: The 2nd link is grouped with the first, so you can try this:

```
foreach($html->find('span[class=gs_ctc]') as $link){
    foreach($link->parent()->parent()->find('div[class=gs_ggs gs_fl]') as $docLink){
        $link1 = $link->next_sibling();
        $link2 = $docLink->first_child();
        if(preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $link2->href) === 1){
            echo $link1->plaintext;
            echo $link1->href;
            echo $link2->href;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rocket .. :) I've tried it, but I only get the titles, i cannot get the links. I've tried in this url = 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=data+mining&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp='

Comment: @user1495052: Silly me, it's `href`, not `src`.

Comment: :) sorry, I have one more question. is it possible to get more specific informations? for example, I just wanna get the first links and titles that have specific second link, for example pdf link only. so, I have to identify the second link first, if it's link that have .pdf extension using this code =`if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $link)) {` then process to get first link and title. thanks !

Comment: @user1495052: Check my edit.  Not sure if that'll work, but try it :P

Comment: it works perfectly ! I feel a little confused in this part -> `=== 1`. what does it mean? It equals `true` ?

Comment: @user1495052: `preg_match` returns `1` if it finds a match `0` if it doesn't or `FALSE` if there was an error.  `===` compares type and value, so I'm just making sure that it's returning `1`.  It's not *really* needed, but I put it there just to be safe.