# Parsing html page that has two different format on the same elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

In the same html pageThere're two different format of the same contain :

the first is :

```
<div class="gs"><h3 class="gsr"><a href="http://www.example1.com/">title1</a>
```

the second is :

```
<div class="gs"><h3 class="gsr"><span class="gsc"></span><a href="http://www.example2.com/">title2</a>
```

How to get links and titles in one code that can handle that two different format with simple_html_dom? 
I've tried this code, but it doesn't work :

```
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gsr]') as $docLink){
   $link = $docLink->first_child();
   echo $link->plaintext;
   echo $link->href;
}
```

Comment: But why have you asked the almost the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533705/parsing-title-and-link-from-html-page

Comment: @Tamil yes, I got new problem. It's different from that page. In the previous question, I just identified one format of html page. Then I realized that there're two format on the same elements. So I made new question here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) there seems to be a concept of Descendant Selectors

```
// Find all <td> in <table> which class=hello 
$es = $html->find('table.hello td');
```

Then

```
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gsr] a') as $link) {
   echo $link->plaintext;
   echo $link->href;
}
```

Should do your job. [I'm not really aware of simple_html_dom btw ;) Just a try]

**EDIT**

There is also nested selectors

```
// Find first <li> in first <ul> 
$e = $html->find('ul', 0)->find('li', 0);
```

So

```
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gsr]') as $docTitle) {
   $link = $docTitle->find('a', 0); //get the first anchor tag
   echo $link->plaintext;
   echo $link->href;
}
```

Should also work

Comment: wow, thanks for bring the concepts. it works ! thank you very much @Tamil :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByTagName($tag);`

It will locate all the specified tags inside the dom...

Refer this link [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)